# github can't commit new file

Tags: github, commit

I am new to github, just created a repo in master branch and commit 45 new files (small ones, less than 100 lines of code per file) .  Now github does not let me commit new files.  After clicking the "+" button to go to a new page for a new file, the green button saying "commit new file" at the bottom of the page is greyed out and no response.  What should I do ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and editing my source file allowed the button to work again. I guess you need to show "edit" to what you're committing as new file (sanity check: is it blank?)